# Change ImageResource Dinamically in Custom ImageView Android

Tags: java, android, imageview

I've working in this error all day and can not solve it. I have a custom `ImageView` as follows:

```
public class UserDirectionView extends ImageView {

private float mDirection;
private Drawable arrow;
private boolean mCorrectPosition;

// constructors...

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (arrow == null) {
        arrow = getDrawable();
        arrow.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        // setImageResource(resId); // Not working
    }

    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(mDirection, getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
    arrow.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}

public void updateDirection(float direction, boolean correctPos) {
    mDirection = direction;
    mCorrectPosition = correctPos;
    invalidate();
}
}
```

I am trying to change the imageResource with `setImageResource(resId)` but nothing is happening.  I've tried to call the method inside of `onDraw` and also outside my class, like so:

```
UserDirectionView mUserHint =  findview....;
mUserHint.setImageResource(resId);
```

But the image is not changing.

I've also tried to call `invalidate`, but didn't work.

How could I change the image resource dinamically?

Comment: you are missing `super.onDraw(canvas)`. Add it as first line

Comment: @Blackbelt That was it!. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `super.onDraw()` call, which takes care of updating the drawable. Add

`super.onDraw(canvas)`

In your `onDraw`